# Render particles inside a certain area

Tags: rendering, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine, particles

[image: Render Particles inside the area of the highlighted object]

Ok so I've got a quick question, is it possible to have particles render when they make contact with a specific object? Essentially make the highlighted object in my scene a domain for the particles, so that when they fall into that area they become visible.

P.s. I'm working in blender render.

Comment: I'm not sure whats your goal here but if you want to draw the shape with particles you might want to give the particle themselves a texture definition  using worldspace coordinates and the image, then have it affect the emission and/or transparency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make particles rendered only in certain areas during animation you should control their size with a texture assigned to particles system. In this case particles will be emitted but will be visible only where texture allows them.

1. Create a cube which will act as a 'domain' for your particles (it will affect particles' appearence).
2. Scale it accordingly with the object. Rotate it 90 degrees by *Y* axis.
   *By default texture of Blend type will use X and Y axes for mapping. In this example cube will be moved by Z axis, hence all the coordinate system should be changed. For this reason the cube will be rotated to rotate its coordinates which will be used as coordinate system for particles' texture. Hence do **not** apply scale and rotation.*
3. Position cube appropriately and keyframe its location.
4. While in Particle System settings go to Textures tab and create new one (make sure that type of textures is set to *Particles* in the top of the Textures tab).
   Switch its type to *Blend* (to use texture as a gradient).
   [image: screenshot of adding particles system texture]
5. Open *Colors* rollout, check *Ramp* and create 2 more color stops to make texture influence in both directions (in this case, +Z and -Z). Choose appropriate *Interpolation* type, in this case used *Constant* for more visible effect. Set up color stops so black is in the corners and white is in the middle.
   [image: screenshot for colors set up for Blend texture]
6. Because texture influence should change together with moving object, that object can be choosed as texture coordinates centre. In *Mapping* rollout choose *Object* and select that scaled and rotated cube from dropdown list.
   [image: screenshot of mapping set up for Blend textures]
7. Lastly, in *Influence* tab uncheck *Time* and check *Size*. The particles' appearence will be controlled by affecting their size instead of density.
   While *Density* will work it won't cause refresh of amount of particles emitted when object used as coordinates centre moves (probably a limitation) and hence this won't work for animation.
   [image: screenshot of Influence setup of texture]

Now particles will be shown only as the cube moves down:

[image: GIF with resulting animation]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for that, it works but when I go to render the scene the particles don't show up? And it renders the cube as being a solid.

Comment: @masterj2001 cube can be easiely marked as non-renderable. As for particles - it's hard to tell the reason, but this doesn't work as expected in Internal. When in BI and with object as texture coordinates, it doesn't take into account object's rotation. More than that, render result depends on camera view (try rotating camera and notice different amount of particles rendered). Probably these are some limitations of particle engine. I don't see any workaround for BI as for now, while this works just fine in Cycles which I tested more at the moment.